# C# / WPF create new button array with multiple function

Tags: c#, wpf, button, dialog

I have wrote a code with this description:
First button calls `FuncPopup();` function, after that every popup dialog creates new button. New button Create `FuncPopup();`. Old buttons should have various behavior.

```
        private void FuncPopup()
    {
        FuncMenu popup = new FuncMenu();
        popup.ShowDialog();
        if (popup.DialogResult.HasValue && popup.DialogResult.Value)
        {
            i++;
            newBtn[i] = new Button();
            FuncGird.Children.Add(newBtn[i]);
            Grid.SetColumn(newBtn[i], i);
            Grid.SetRow(newBtn[i], j);
            newBtn[i].Click += (sender, e) => clicked(i);
        }
    }
    void clicked(int g) {
        if (g >= i) 
        {
            FuncPopup(); 
        }
        else (g < i){
            OtherFunction();
        }
    }
```

`i` is a global variable. I expect Old buttons run `OtherFunction();` but they always run `FuncPopup();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because as you said `i` is global variable, and you attach the following handler:

```
 newBtn[i].Click += (sender, e) => clicked(i);
```

And you increment `i` all the time. You might think that value of `i` is fixed at the moment you attach this handler but it's not so. `i` in `clicked(i)` is the same global variable, which increments with every call. So `g` always equals `i` in that handler, and so for all buttons `FuncPopup` is called.

Instead save `i` to local variable and use that:

```
int tmp = i;
newBtn[i].Click += (sender, e) => clicked(tmp);
```

Comment: Great job, I have defined tmp variable locally, the result became what I expected.